# Thread 1: "time interval must be greater than 0" if notification schedule was in the past

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeQIw.png)

When I press the button before the specified time (notidhuhr which updates everyday) notifications work perfectly, but if I press it after the app hangs and crashes giving me the above error. How to fix?

Comment: Add your code in question instead of adding image of code

Comment: You can't schedule notifications in the past. Your fix here depends on what your app should do if the button is clicked after `notidhuhr`. Should it just not send a notification? Should it send a notification at the current time? Should it calculate a new time to schedule the notification for?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.